# Best practices and methods to draw shapes, lines, beziers, texts etc on the canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've noticed a lot of the time that whenever I try to draw many objects at once on HTML5 canvas that the colors don't always appear in the way I want them to, things just don't render, etc.

How should I go about drawing many different things at once? Should I draw basic shapes on their own, then text, then lines, etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the simplest, you need to make sure you call:

`ctx.beginPath()` before every new shape you intend to draw, if they are different colors.

Or to call `ctx.stroke()` only once, if the paths you intend to draw are all the same color.

As an example, imagine drawing two lines, both black:

```js
ctx.beginPath()
// Draw one line:
ctx.moveTo(x0, y0);
ctx.lineTo(x1, y1);
ctx.stroke(); // Stroke that line


// Draw another line:
ctx.moveTo(x2, y2);
ctx.lineTo(x3, y3);
// This does not only stroke the second line
// Since you never called beginPath() again, it strokes
// Both the first and second line as two sub-paths of the same path
ctx.stroke(); // Strokes both line
```

With the second call to `stroke()` you will be re-stroking the first line. This is a big problem if you change colors of course, but even if you don't, stroking the first line twice will make it slightly thicker.

The "best practice" solution, by that I mean the most efficient way to draw, is to draw *all paths of the same color* with only one call to `beginPath`, and one call to `stroke`:

```js
ctx.beginPath()
// Draw one line:
ctx.moveTo(x0, y0);
ctx.lineTo(x1, y1);
// Do not stroke

// Draw another line:
ctx.moveTo(x2, y2);
ctx.lineTo(x3, y3);

ctx.stroke(); // Strokes both lines with the same color
```

You cannot do this if you plan to draw different colors. You must create a new path by calling `beginPath` each time, and calling `stroke` each time:

```js
// Draw one line:
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(x0, y0);
ctx.lineTo(x1, y1);
ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
ctx.stroke();

// Draw another line:
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(x2, y2);
ctx.lineTo(x3, y3);
ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
ctx.stroke();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this good answer! I assumed I was just going to get downvoted to hell with no response as to either why or at least any solution, but you answered cleanly, thank you.

Comment: Don't worry about the haters, have fun coding 